# ReactiveUI and responding to changes in a list

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, reactiveui

I'm totally new to ReactiveUI and need the help of you experts out there to figure out how to achieve the following.

I have a UWP app in C# with a page that contains a ListView which shows a bunch of items (doesn't matter what type of items, so let's assume it shows a bunch of integers).

When the Page.Loaded is called, I send a query to a server, get the results (array of integers), and populates the ListView with the results.

What I'd like to do is to show a ProgressRing until the data is received from the server **and** the list is done populating (i.e. new items are all added). Once these two actions are done I'd like to hide the ProgressRing.

And I'd like to do the above using ReactiveUI but haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with UWP, but i can provide an example with WPF, which i hope will be useful.
In this example i used progress ring from [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)

ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _isLoading;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Load = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () =>
        {
            // Simulating a long running task, like DB query
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            // Populating list
            Items.Clear();
            Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Where(x => x%2 == 0));
        });
        Load.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsLoading, out _isLoading);
    }

    public bool IsLoading => _isLoading.Value;
    public ReactiveList<int> Items { get; } = new ReactiveList<int>();
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Load { get; }
}
```

View

```
public partial class MainWindow : IViewFor<MainViewModel>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(MainViewModel), typeof(MainWindow));
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.Items, x => x.ListView.ItemsSource);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.IsLoading, x => x.ProgressRing.IsActive);
        this.Events().Loaded.Subscribe(_ => this.ViewModel.Load.Execute().Subscribe());
    }
    public MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (MainViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (MainViewModel)value; }
    }
}
<Window x:Class="ProgressRing.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                  Title="MainWindow">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemStringFormat="Item {0}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <controls:ProgressRing x:Name="ProgressRing" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```